# Obtain the contents of a div tag that doesn't have a class attribute using python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I tried to obtain the text inside a `<div>` tag but was not able. I am trying to obtain the this text:

```
MsiExec.exe /X{42435041-332D-5350-00A7-A758B70C0F00}
```

This tag is not enclosed inside any div class.

```
<div style="margin-top: 10px;"><span class="colorlt">Uninstaller:</span> MsiExec.exe /X{42435041-332D-5350-00A7-A758B70C0F00}</div>
```

Can somebody pls tell me how it is to done using python?
I am using BeautifulSoup to scrap the page.

Comment: How do you identify the `<div>`? Do you look for any `<div>`s that don't have any CSS class? And then you want to extract the text inside them? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Is this the entire contents of the scraped page?  If so, try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup('<div style="margin-top: 10px;"><span class="colorlt">Uninstaller:</span> MsiExec.exe /X{42435041-332D-5350-00A7-A758B70C0F00}</div>', 'html.parser')
print soup.div.text
```

> Uninstaller: MsiExec.exe /X{42435041-332D-5350-00A7-A758B70C0F00}

If your scraped page contains other divs, this may not work.